how to parse C++ code symbols completely in Source Insight
I am reading gcc stdlibc++'s source code in Source Insight, but many symbols are not parsed.
When I want to see some functions or class definitions, it throws an error saying "symbols not found".
For example, I am reading "shared_ptr.h", but I cannot Jump To Defination of class _Sp_counted_base even it is defined, and many other symbols are not loaded in the Symbol Window too(just as you see on the left side of the source code)

My project's root directory was set correctly and all files were added into project.
I tried to synchronize all the files, but failed to solve it.
So, what caused the inability to correctly parse symbols, and what I should do to solve the problem?

Last time I checked the standard library headers, it was pretty complicated with quite a few conditional compilation blocks and folders.  I haven't used source-insight, but unless it has all the capabilities of a preprocessor, and you've defined the necessary macros, it probably treats implementations as #if 0'd out.

Not what you are asking about, but you should probably not bother with studying the TR1 code. It is from a "Technical Report", halfway between C++98 and C++11. Pretty ancient by now!

I don't know how your project is structured.
If the symbol you're missing is from a compiler lib, like GCC, you need to create a new project with all the h files from the compiler install dir, and later add it (the project) as additional symbols in the project settings (look for "import symbols").
Sometimes a declaration of a symbol uses a macro that interferes with the parsing, you need to add the macro the C.tom file so the parser will disregard it. Look for token file in the SI help.
